# Cannot create folders via FTP or cPanel after git clone

Tags: git, ftp, cpanel

I am currently working on a php project (drupal based) with two environments: development & live.
My workflow: editing on develop -> commit -> push to github -> clone (first) / pull on live.

So far, so good. I cloned the latest version and copied the database. But when I try to upload the settings file for the live environment or create a files folder for uploads, I get

`553 Can't open that file: Permission denied` and `550 Can't create directory: Permission denied`

Then tried to create the files folder via cPanel filemanager, but still getting "Permission denied".

Does anyone have a clue what happened? I cloned via ssh, if that helps. Hope I am not creating a duplicate here, but I could not find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, probably/hopefully nobody will run into it, because it has to do with being logged in as root user and as root user I probably should have thought about this. **But** here is the answer anyway.

Dev and live environment have two different users, own cPanel login, ftp, etc. Let's call them *duser* and *luser*. Everything fine until here. Both environments are on the same server.

But I remember when I first wanted to install git on the dev environment, I did not have the permission. So I logged in as root and installed git. Then when I logged back in as *duser* and wanted to use git, I still did not have the permission. So since then I always log in as root to be able to use git. (Probably I could and should have configured my server to be able to use git as *duser* and *luser*.)

**Long story short:** `git clone` as root makes all the cloned files and folders being owned by root. So my cPanel and ftp user had no permission to change anything. Used `chown` to fix the user & group and everything works fine again.